# Cross variation not independent Brownian motions

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

How can I calculate the cross variation between a standard Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and the process $(B_t^{\tau})_{t\geq \tau}$ defined as $B_t^{\tau}= B_t-B_{t-\tau}$? Here $\tau$ is just a positive fixed number.

I tried to use the definition of cross variation. So, let  $\Pi=\{t_0=\tau, t_1, \cdots, t_n=t\}$ be a partition of the interval $[\tau,t]$. Then, for all $t\geq \tau$

$$\langle B, {B}^{\tau}\rangle_t = \lim_{\|\Pi\| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (B_{t_{i}}- B_{t_{i-1}})({B}_{t_{i}}^{\tau}- {B}^{\tau}_{t_{i-1}})$$
where $\|\Pi\|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(t_i-t_{i-1})$.

Then
$$\langle B, {B}^{\tau}\rangle_t = \lim_{\|\Pi\| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (B_{t_{i}} -B_{t_{i-1}})^2 - \lim_{\|\Pi\| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (B_{t_{i}} -B_{t_{i-1}}) (B_{t_{i}-\tau}- B_{t_{i-1}-\tau})\\ = (t-\tau) - \lim_{\|\Pi\| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (B_{t_{i}} -B_{t_{i-1}}) (B_{t_{i}-\tau}- B_{t_{i-1}-\tau}) $$
where the last equation follows since the quadratic variation of the standard Brownian motion on $[\tau,t]$ is just $t-\tau$.

Comment: Hallo and welcome. What are your ideas for the solution? What do you conclude from the statistical properties of the increments of Brownian motion?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please document your existing efforts by editing your question? It would be a better place than the comments.

Comment: Now if the granularity of the subdivision is smaller than $τ$, the increments in the product are independent and thus orthogonal in the "expectation scalar product".

Comment: @LutzL This is often called the *mesh* of the subdivision. Nice hint, by the way.